# Rewrite Parallax-Script so it reads multiple Classes instead of one Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

Heyo,

is there any way I can get this script:

```
function parallax (){
    var paralax_effect = document.getElementById('div1');
    paralax_effect.style.top = -(window.pageYOffset / 4)+'px';
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', parallax, false);
```

to run multiple `Classes` instead of one `Id`?

I tried this:

```
function parallax (){
    var paralax_effect = document.getElementsByClassName('div1');
    paralax_effect.style.top = -(window.pageYOffset / 4)+'px';
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', parallax, false);
```

but this somehow doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns not a single element but a whole list of elements, whereas `getElementById` (notice the difference in the word Element/Elements) returns only a single element.

So in your second code, you store a list of elements with the class "div1" in `var paralax_effect`. In order to manipulate those elements you have to loop over them with `for`. Example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < paralax_effect.length; i++) {
    current_element = paralax_effect[i]
    current_element.style.top = -(window.pageYOffset / 4)+'px';
}
```

This requires your HTML to have at least one element with `class="div1"`.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks for the help and explanation. You saved my day :D